# In Taskfile how to use a dotenv file produced by one task in another task

Tags: taskfile

In Taskfile I would like to use a dotenv file produced by one task in another task. Consider the following example where `make-env` task produces a `.env` file and `my-task` task depends on `make-env` and loads `.env`.

```yaml
---
version: 3

tasks:
  make-env:
    cmds:
      - echo "MY_VAR=MY_VALUE" >> ./.env
  my-task:
    deps:
      - make-env
    dotenv:
      - ./.env
    cmds:
      - echo "MY_VAR = $MY_VAR"
```

I would expect to see `MY_VAR = MY_VALUE` after running the `task my-task` command, but it is `MY_VAR =`  instead. It seems like it loads the dotenv file first (but does not fail because the file does not exist yet?) and then executes all dependencies.

A workaround that I considered is to run `make-env` task as a step in the `my-task` command and source the dotenv file, but I would really like to leverage Taskfile's deps and dotenv constructs.

Is there a way to ensure that all dependencies have run before the dotnev files are loaded?

Comment: In my case the issue was with task file dir != CWD: `cd /dir`, then `task -t path/to/file.yml`. If `.env` file is under `/dir`, it is ignored, but when I move it to `/dir/path/to` it works. Dotenv setting is set like this: `dotenv: ['.env']`.